Fugue Structure
I've been wanting to learn to write a fugue for a while. I spent some time learning counterpoint with a teacher starting with species, I think I got a good grasp on counterpoint now.
How do you write a fugue exposition, I've looked into many sources, some say different things so I'm a bit confused. My current knowledge of an exposition is each voice introduces the subject in alternating tonic and dominant, when a voice finishes they play a countersubject to accompany the other voice playing the subject.
But after that I'm stuck on what to do next?

Your brief description of a fugal exposition is essentially correct: it is most common for fugues to have alternating initial entrances on tonic and dominant.  You continue this alternation for as many voices as there are in the fugue (typically 3-6 voices, though 3-4 is most common).
A specific countersubject is optional though rather common, and it's best to compose this in "double counterpoint" (also known as "invertible counterpoint"), so that it can occur both above and below the subject and still make contrapuntal sense.  (Practically, this means being careful about uses of fourths and fifths, since fifths are consonant but invert to fourths, which should be treated as a dissonance when above the bass in standard classical counterpoint.)
In some cases, composers use multiple countersubjects: e.g., first entrance in tonic in voice A, then second entrance in dominant in voice B with countersubject 1 in A, then third entrance in tonic in voice C, with countersubject 1 in B and countersubject 2 in A.  Having multiple countersubjects in invertible counterpoint allows you to permute these in different voices later in the fugue and can substantially decrease the amount of new music you'll need to write while still sounding "fresh" at new entrances of the subject.
After the exposition is complete, the general plan varies significantly from fugue to fugue.  In general, there is a series of episodes (which don't contain the subject), which typically -- though not always -- modulate to another key, after which there will be an entrance of the subject again in at least one voice in the new key.  Although not required, new entrances are often accompanied by countersubject(s) too.
Episodes are often built on modulating sequences, but that's just one common option.  Episodes often also have some melodic motive derived from the fugue subject or one of the countersubjects.
A fugue will usually go through several such modulating episodes and typically visit somewhere around 2-5 closely related keys before modulating back to the tonic at the end.  There will generally be a final entrance of the fugue subject in the tonic (perhaps multiple entrances).  Often there's some sort of coda or codetta which may or may not be related to previous motives and wraps things up to a final cadence in the tonic.
This is the general blueprint, but again it varies a lot.  There are all sorts of more advanced techniques possible, such as stretto (where multiple voices enter in an overlapping fashion with the fugue subject), pedal points (where some voice has a very long held note -- most typically the dominant note of the key -- as versions of the subject or other previous motives are played against it), counterexpositions (where the exposition is followed by another sort of exposition with the voices entering in a different order), double expositions (where there are two distinct subjects, each with their own exposition), etc.
The best way to learn about fugue writing is to refer to one of the many books specifically on the subject, coupled with some analysis of actual fugues by composers in the style you wish to emulate.
If you've only just studied basic counterpoint, I'd recommend instead starting with a two-voice structure to begin with, learning to, say, emulate a Bach invention.  Those typically have staggered initial entries with shorter motives (rather than full-blown fugue subjects), but they will teach you how to structure an entire composition -- i.e., visiting multiple closely-related keys, reusing motives, writing modulating sequences to get you there and spin out motives, and structuring strong cadences in the intervening keys.
After you can write a good two-voice piece, then try moving onto a three-voice fugue.  Learn how to write two countersubjects in triple counterpoint with the subject, then use permutations of those for future entrances of the subject. Coupled with a good knowledge of modulating sequences, how to spin out motives, and how to write good cadences, a three-voice fugue may be within your reach then.

So, invertible counterpoint allows you to play the same countersubjects on a lower or higher voice? Is that the entire structure of an exposition just the presentation of the subjects? Also in more voices than 2, do you require additional countersubjects for the other voices playing?

also how do you write a good fugue subject

@mathisdagoat: For beginning students, it isn't recommended to start by writing your own subject. Many classical composers wrote fugue based on pre-existing subjects, and I'd recommend that at the outset. And yes, invertible counterpoint allows you to use the same countersubject both above and below the existing subject. The exposition is typically just the entries of the subject in each voice (sometimes there can be short transitions between some entries).

As for countersubjects, it's not like each voice gets its own countersubject. As I gave an example in my answer, sometimes you can more than one.  So, in a three-voice fugue, when the third voice enters, there might be countersubject 1 in one voice, and countersubject 2 in another voice, both of them against the original subject of the fugue. But this isn't strictly necessary - sometimes the third voice (and others) are just "free" counterpoint each time the subject appears.

A fugal exposition is traditionally four statements of the subject. The first in the tonic key such as C major or A minor. The second statement is in the dominant key (a C major fugue would answer in G major; an A minor fugue in E minor.) The third and fourth statements do the same tonic, then dominant. One can use any ordering of voices (bass, tenor, alto, soprano for a 4-voice fugue, or bass, alto, soprano, tenor, etc.). There are details about fitting the statements together. Classical and Romantic era fugues use other key arrangements.
Then, there is a fantasy-like play on the subject, usually wandering around a bunch of keys, those directed to finishing with two (perhaps modified) statements of the theme in the dominant followed by the tonic keys.
There are several books on the subject of fugues, Imogene Horsley's comes to mind.

"A fugal exposition is traditionally four statements of the subject": more precisely, it is one statement of the subject per voice, where the number of voices may or may not be four.  It's probably best to start with fewer voices.  Also, this post describes a so-called "real answer" but, especially in earlier fugues, the "tonal" answer is more common, where the answer isn't truly in the dominant but has one interval altered so that it is centered on the dominant note but remains in the tonic key.
